# Is there any way to call the feature file with scenarios divided by @env tags?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to call some feature file with scenarios divided by @env tag. For example scenario with tag @env=dev and other scenario with tag @env=stage.

But when I'm calling it -- all scenarios are executing, for all envs. Is it any way to make it working, or I should try other realization of it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `env` is a "special" tag and for this to work, you need to set the `karate.env` on the command line: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#environment-tags

Maybe you didn't set the Karate environment.

Comment: I set it, but it still doesn't work.
Original Feature:
`Feature: Original
Background:
* call read('classpath:functions/features/helper.feature')`
In the `helper` feature I set up variables depending on env:
`Feature: Helper
@env=Dev
Scenario: Prepare dev variables
* def var1 = ...
* def var2 = ...
@env=stage
Scenario: Prepare stage variables
* def var1 = ...
* def var2 = ...'

But, when I run this test with the command line -- I see that in the background initiating variables from both helper scenarios. Running like this:
`gradle clean test -Dkarate.env="Dev"`

Comment: @PavelKozhukhar sorry I give up. follow this process, or lets hope someone else can help you: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue