# Calling a Karate feature file that has multiple Scenarios with @env tags runs all Scenarios

Tags: karate

I have a feature file with 2 scenarios that have @env tags. I am calling this in another feature file and I expect only one Scenario to run but both do.

```
@ignore
Feature: Get Karate Constants

  @env=local,mock,qa,e2e,perf
  Scenario: Preprod constants
    * def results = read('classpath:data/karate/KarateConstants.json')

  @env=stage,prod
  Scenario: Prod constants
    * def results = read('classpath:data/karate/ProdKarateConstants.json')

---------------------------------
Feature: other file

  Background:
    And def constants = callonce read('classpath:karate/helpers/GetKarateConstants.feature')
```

I am calling this via the CLI `mvn clean verify -Dkarate.env=mock` and am using `karate-junit5:v1.2.0`. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74473477/is-there-any-way-to-call-the-feature-file-with-scenarios-divided-by-env-tags) but hopefully this post will have more information for debugging. If not, I'll look into submitting an [issue](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue).

I tried using only singular @env tags like `@env=mock` and `@env=prod` but the problem persists. I can confirm both scenarios are running through the HTML report when I make a call purposely fail.

Comment: it is likely there is a bug. being a relatively rarely used feature, it may take a while for us to get to it. a way to replicate will certainly help, we encourage contributions and I would urge you to submit a PR (or do try to get someone to)